# jQuery onFocus textarea, then on keyup submit

Tags: jquery

Hi i was im trying to make a jquery ajax submit form, and im currently trying to make restrictions for submiting a form.
i want the user to press enter to submit a form and not press on a submit button, 
but only when the user is focusing on a textarea/input field it will submit when he/she presses enter!

i have attempted to make my own code and edit in it to see what works, 
and i have figured this code out, but it doesnt work quite well :(

```
$('.addformtextarea').focus(function() {

$(document).keyup(function(e){
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13: //enter
        //code to be 
        break;
    }
});
```

.addformtextarea is the textarea to be focused on.

and does return false; behave the same as break; ? because i have a return false; right before break;

thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.addformtextarea').keyup(function(e){
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 13: //enter
        //code to be 
        return false;
    }
});
```

You don't need to worry about focus, because the keyup would only fire if the input has focus.

The break only breaks out of the switch, you need return false to prevent the automatic submit, if you are doing it with the code.

Comment: thanks a lot!
and thanks for answering my 2nd question return false doesnt mess with switch/case ? thats good news :) 
and it works now :D

Comment: consider using event.which instead of event.keyCode

Answer (score 1):

You would probably be better off binding to the `keyup` event of the input:

```
$(".addformtextarea").keyup(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 13: //enter
        //code to be 
        break;
    }
});
```

Notice that I've used `which` instead of `keyCode`. That's just because jQuery normalizes the event object to remove any cross-browser inconsistencies.

The problem with your current code is that once the `focus` event is fired, the `keyup` event is bound to the `document` and will trigger whether the element has focus or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter');
        // $('your_form').submit();
    }
});
```

If the user is typing in the textarea, then wouldn't it be focused? I don't really like redundancy.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cjTu9/4/**